# Win 10 CHKDSK /F /R /X skipping to login

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk

Tried to run CHKDSK /F /R /X this morning, unfortunately, after restarting to begin the process I get the press any button to skip part (I don't press anything) and it moves onto repairing C drive, but after 5-10 seconds of being on that message, screen cuts to black, then the "please wait" screen and onto the login screen.

No idea what I'm doing wrong, and I can find very little about it online. The only suggestion I found was to check event viewer, but there's nothing there.

edit: Initial issue to use CHKDSK were 2 unexpected shutdowns a few hours apart when I went AFK for a few minutes and as such didn't catch any error messages. When I came back I was greeted by the intel boot agent (No boot device found). No issues with connections or boot order, so I decided to use CHKDSK to see if part of my HDD had problems that were causing this.

SMART attributes (seems fine) :

[image]

Comment: Looks like XY problem, tell why you're trying to run chkdsk? What's the problem you're trying to solve with it? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You should know that `chkdsk` is a dangerous tool, in that its "fixing" can cause data destruction. It's much better to run `chkdsk` for check only, without these parameters, and it would help if you could add the output to your post. If you suspect a disk problem, add a screenshot of the SMART attributes of the disk to your post. If you don't have a product for that, you could use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), Storage section.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen edited post

Comment: @harrymc added link to screenshot on OP as well as some extra details

Comment: @someguy Boot to WinRE and run `ChkDsk` from there on `C:` _(in WinRE, `C:` is usually not the OS partition, so verify first prior to running, either via `notepad` > `Ctrl`+`O` or `diskpart` > `lis vol` > `exit`)_. `ChkDsk` on `C:` should always be run from WinRE so the output can be seen, of which prevents the issues being experienced.